# How many people lived in the Mexican territories annexed by the US?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, california, mexico, demography

What was the population of the areas annexed by the [US from Mexico in the 1840s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUnitedStatesExpansion.png)? Basically, "Texas," "California" and the area in between?

Answer (score 6):

In an article on the [Treaty of Guadalupe-Hidalgo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Guadalupe_Hidalgo), PBS offers the following estimate:

> At the time of the treaty, approximately 80,000 Mexicans lived in the ceded territory, which comprised only about 4 percent of Mexico’s population. *[PBS](http://www.pbs.org/kpbs/theborder/history/timeline/6.html)*

Comment: I don't know how true this is, but a source I read once stated that a lot of those folks chose to emigrate back south to Mexico. It also stated that when word got out about the discovery of gold at Sutter's Mill earlier in the year, a lot of them turned around and went back. :-)

Comment: I would not be surprised at all;  the US removed from the treaty provisions to protect the rights of those in the ceded territory. I suspect that many of those were not treated fairly. And it was marginal territory until irrigation was provided.  So Sutter's mill would have been a prudent choice.

Answer (score 5):

I can only find figures excluding Indians. According to Weber's *The Mexican Frontier*, California had 7,300 in 1845, and New Mexico had 65,000 in 1846. Texas in 1846, according to the [Texas State Historical Association](https://tshaonline.org/handbook/online/articles/ulc01), had 125,000 people.